# Setting BasicHTTPBinding for WCF service in Visual Web Express 2010

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I'm creating a WCF service using Visual Web Developer Express 2010.  I'd like to try out various bindings for educational purposes.

My memory from 2008 is that the web.config automatically included a section in  for `<services>`, which I then would edit to change the endpoint binding, for example to basicHttpBinding

However my autogenerated 2010 service does not include `<services>` and any child endpoint or binding details under `<system.serviceModel>` (see web.config below).  Do I need to add this  element to the Web.config manually, or is there an alternative way that this should be configured?  Or is this a limitation of the Express edition?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false 
               and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
               set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
               to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

UPDATE 1 - I've found the following link which seems to describe the same behaviour - investigating now: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/166429.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Visual Studio doesn't matter here - it's the version of the .NET framework that is causing your confusion.  In .NET 4.0 there are default WCF settings which means that a service can be hosted without any configuration.

MSDN [Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) will explain more.

If you create the project as a .NET 3.5 project the configuration will be required (and will be added when you 'add new WCF service').

You *can* add the configuration in .NET 4.0, but if you are new to WCF it's easier if it were automatically generated so you had a starting point to work from.

Comment: So presumably I need to go ahead and add bindings to the webconfig to enable a different configuration e.g.  <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding messageEncoding="Mtom"/> <!-- notice there’s no name attribute -->

      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

Comment: Yes - if you want to change the binding on a configuration-free service you need to add a `binding` tag, and also a `service` tag which links that binding to your service.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that WCF 4 creates a default end point if one isn't defined.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

> In an effort to make the overall WCF experience just as easy as ASMX,
>   WCF 4 comes with a new “default configuration” model that completely
>   removes the need for any WCF configuration. If you don’t provide any
>   WCF configuration for a particular service, the WCF 4 runtime
>   automatically configures your service with some standard endpoints and
>   default binding/behavior configurations. This makes it much easier to
>   get a WCF service up and running, especially for those who aren’t
>   familiar with the various WCF configuration options and are happy to
>   accept the defaults, at least to get started.